# Android Studio Artic Fox not connecting multiple devices wirelessly and not attaching debugger

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-studio-3.0

I recently updated my studio and got the artic fox version. I use multiple devices for debugging and I don't like my devices connected with the wire, so I connect all of them Wirelessly.
It used to work flawlessly before. But after the update when I write the command :

```
adb connect 192.1681.101:5555
```

Device A gets connected. and when I type the 2nd command :

```
adb connect 192.1681.103:5554
```

The message shows that the device is connected but I cannot see the device when I try to run the code. Am I missing anything here? I also tried to connect on the same port, it shows the same message but the device is not showing.
Also when I am trying to attach the debugger its not getting attached. Is this some sort of bug in the arctic fox update?

Comment: I also cannot attach a debugger to a physical device on AF, when wired or wireless.

Comment: Also having a internet issue with the emulator after updating Android Studio to Artic Fox. Says connected but no internet